How to host ASP.NET Core MVC project at live server
We have a project & access of live server. We copied code from server & made changes. Now the mail point is here how to make it liver.
I am very confused hot to make it live. We don't have any TFS/Git access for the same. Just only live server and code.
I saw few thing and found in ISS its refer Publish folder code.
Can we make directly change in the same solution & or should we make copy of it. If copy then how we will publish to the server and make it live.

First of all, if you just copy the published file which just contains the dll we couldn't modify it and re-publish it. You need make sure you have the source codes for the project.
If you have the project source codes and you could run it at local side, you could make changes for it, you could use some tool like Visual studio or Visual studio code to modify, build and publish it.
More details about how to build and publish the project inside the VS, you could refer to this article.
Some steps like this:
1.Open your project in Visual Studio.
2.Right-click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select "Publish".
3.Choose "Folder" as the publish target.
4Select a folder on your local machine where the published files will be placed.
4.Click "Publish".
After publishing the projects, you will have the published files, as you said you have live server and it host the application, you could copy all the files to previous IIS hosted application and restart the IIS.
